What’s causing this damp patch
I have this damp patch on the bottom corner of my wall next to the non sliding part of a sliding door. It leads to the balcony of my apartment and no water gets to this corner from the outside. The wall is only crumbling on that lower part. There is an aircon unit installed on the other side of the window.
What could be causing this?

If it's a rental apartment, it's on the landlord to fix.

Could be coming from anywhere above, including running across a beam from the far side of the house. You need someone to inspect the building from outside, and if that doesn't resolve it to open up the plaster and look for evidence inside.
Bring in a local pro.
